# Anypoint Setting Flow Reference Display Name

Tags: anypoint-studio

Since I did an update to Anypoint Studio a while ago, whenever I add a Flow Reference and set the Flow Name it is pointing to, the Display Name of the Flow Reference is changed automatically to the name of that flow. Anypoint will sometimes rename it even when I just open the properties of that flow so I constantly lose the name I have set.

Has anyone else come across this? I've looked if it is setting that I can turn off but cannot find anything, and am wondering if it is a bug within Anypoint.

Anypoint Version 6.2.2
OS - Windows 10 Pro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been speaking to Mulesoft Support and they are aware of the bug and apparently it will be fixed in version 6.4 release towards the end of June 17.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked this my anypoint studio and studio behaves the same and whenever we add any new flow and refer the flow using flow reference the flow reference name automatically changed to flow name. Although it seems correct for me as the flow we are referring using flow reference should show the same name.